# Background image position and content scrolling

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a profile page where content scrolls over a an image.
Here the sample

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sectionHeight = $('.service-logo').height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  // $('.content').height(
  //   $(window).height() - $('.header').height() - $('.footer').height()
  // );
  console.log($('.content').height());
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.service-logo').offset().top + ((sectionHeight - windowHeight) / 2)) {
    $('.service-logo').addClass('bg-scroll');
    console.log(sectionHeight, windowHeight);
  } else {
    $('.service-logo').removeClass('bg-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content,
.content2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.content .text {
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.service-logo {
  height: 1280px;
  background-image: url(https://previews.123rf.com/images/antonioguillem/antonioguillem1309/antonioguillem130900025/22071391-beautiful-model-woman-posing-standing-isolated-on-a-white-background.jpg);
  background-color: #f2eee3;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
}

.bg-scroll {
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
  this is the header
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam non laoreet magna. Curabitur viverra velit quis quam venenatis, ac mattis massa fermentum. Cras vel consequat sem. Vivamus tellus leo, pellentesque ac quam eget, maximus tincidunt risus.
      Vestibulum vel tristique sem. Donec consequat, magna vitae semper pretium, turpis est suscipit libero, vitae rhoncus tortor mi ut lorem. Cras id elit ac libero elementum dignissim non vel nibh. Nunc maximus dolor in risus molestie dignissim. Phasellus
      eget neque ipsum. Phasellus malesuada dapibus imperdiet.</p>

    <p>Aenean id blandit nisi. Vestibulum bibendum, justo a vehicula egestas, nunc velit ultrices mi, at cursus dui sapien non magna. Nulla et sollicitudin libero. In finibus nulla eget imperdiet sagittis. Mauris rutrum erat vitae dui accumsan feugiat. Mauris
      auctor felis sed mi eleifend, non pulvinar lorem convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam purus nulla, dignissim id sapien vel, imperdiet tristique nisl. Aliquam varius odio sed velit dignissim, sed consectetur
      ante malesuada. Cras tincidunt ex at odio dignissim rutrum. Sed sit amet tristique nunc, a euismod metus. Aliquam et ipsum dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer nulla odio, interdum
      ac leo in, condimentum fringilla orci. Quisque at pulvinar sapien, non egestas tortor. Vestibulum quis augue dictum, imperdiet tortor non, euismod velit.</p>

    <p>Integer cursus vel erat quis finibus. Vivamus mauris libero, sollicitudin sit amet diam in, accumsan laoreet mauris. Nulla pharetra imperdiet turpis, nec tincidunt est posuere id. Donec pretium eleifend lacus non semper. Maecenas porta neque vitae
      massa consectetur blandit. Mauris accumsan malesuada consectetur. In vel purus ac justo pretium venenatis eu at est. Aliquam bibendum nisi mi, vel sollicitudin purus rutrum nec. Quisque et sagittis nulla, nec ultrices sapien. Sed iaculis libero
      vel orci condimentum imperdiet. Curabitur blandit dignissim sem, scelerisque ultricies sem pretium sed. Nullam placerat turpis ac ullamcorper gravida.</p>

    <p>Morbi nec ullamcorper augue, sed suscipit tellus. Donec et porta justo. Donec ultrices lectus ut arcu tincidunt consectetur. Proin massa diam, mattis ullamcorper mattis a, scelerisque vitae augue. Nam a risus convallis, ultricies est at, tincidunt
      ipsum. Nullam non posuere sapien, eget tincidunt tellus. Curabitur eu congue tortor, sed lobortis erat. Morbi et sollicitudin leo. Mauris at dignissim odio. In tempor volutpat ex eu aliquam. Pellentesque aliquam tortor sit amet porta blandit. Sed
      ut elit sit amet metus euismod luctus ut vel orci. Nunc vel ultrices erat, ut tincidunt lectus. Integer quis enim feugiat, condimentum enim id, malesuada ante.</p>

    <p>Maecenas accumsan pellentesque aliquet. Morbi tempor lectus tortor, vitae molestie ante fringilla eu. Etiam quam nulla, feugiat posuere placerat eu, hendrerit sit amet libero. Mauris non facilisis magna, sed tincidunt urna. Aliquam tellus enim, porta
      a felis vitae, blandit consequat quam. Morbi ac dolor non nunc tempor posuere at et ipsum. Suspendisse vel sem lacus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content2 service-logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  this is the footer
</div>
```

My problem is that the content text div background is still white and the scroll process is not exactly what I am looking for.

I would like the scroll process to scroll the image up when the content ends. Does it make sense?

Can Someone help me with this?

Comment: Don't use `on('scroll')`, rather use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) . With this you can check if an element is in the viewport / intersecting with another element.

Comment: I'm lost... How should I do that with jquery?